# How do I only print categories that belong to the current post? This snippet shows all the categories in the site

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, printing

I have this snippet that shows all taxonomy list in the site, that belongs to a specific vocabulary.
Instead of printing the whole list, how do I just print the terms that belong to the node I'm actually loading?
I have a Drupal 7 installation.

This is how I print the id of the node I´m at: `<?php print $node->nid;?>`

```
<?php 
$vid = 11; //vocabulary id

$query = "SELECT tid, name, count
FROM (
SELECT td.tid AS tid, name, COUNT(td.tid) AS count
FROM taxonomy_term_data AS td
JOIN taxonomy_index AS tn
  ON td.tid = tn.tid
JOIN node AS n
  ON n.nid = tn.nid
WHERE td.vid = ". $vid ."
  AND n.status = 1
GROUP BY td.tid
ORDER BY count DESC
) AS t
ORDER BY name ASC";
$result = db_query($query);
foreach($result as $term) {
    if ($term->count > 0) {
      echo l($term->name, "taxonomy/term/$term->tid").' ('.$term->count.')'.'<br/>';
    }
}
 ?>
```

Comment: Have you tried to extend the WHERE clause with sg like "AND n.nid = ".$node->id ?

Comment: That did the trick! THANKS!! I´ll post the complete correct answer, in case anyone else needs it. Would you like to post it so I can set your answer as the correct one? Or should I?

Comment: Thanks, however I guess **sumoanand**'s answer is more suitable. I'll post my answer though :)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest not to run extra query for this.
This information should be available in $node object.

Just print it [print_r($node) ] and see what exactly is the taxonomy object name($node->taxonomy) & how taxonomy information is structured  & use that to display category on node page or node teaser.

On other pages, you can use node_load to 1st load the node and then do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

**sumoand**'s answer is more optimal in this case, however for some sql practicing here's the exact solution the way you imagined:

```
<?php 
$vid = 11; //vocabulary id

$query = "SELECT tid, name, count
FROM (
SELECT td.tid AS tid, name, COUNT(td.tid) AS count
FROM taxonomy_term_data AS td
JOIN taxonomy_index AS tn
  ON td.tid = tn.tid
JOIN node AS n
  ON n.nid = tn.nid
WHERE td.vid = ". $vid ."
  AND n.status = 1
  AND n.nid = ".$node->id."
GROUP BY td.tid
ORDER BY count DESC
) AS t
ORDER BY name ASC";
$result = db_query($query);
foreach($result as $term) {
    if ($term->count > 0) {
      echo l($term->name, "taxonomy/term/$term->tid").' ('.$term->count.')'.'<br/>';
    }
}
?>
```